# Trigger builds for MRs and pushes on main branch

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I'm trying to configure my job to build all Merge Requests and pushes on main branch (For every approved MR, to update the baseline on Sonarqube).

To trigger builds I'm using the gitlab-plugin on Jenkins.

Right now I have this configuration:

```
triggers {
            gitlab(
                    triggerOnPush: true,
                    triggerOnMergeRequest: true,
                    noteRegex: "(?i)(Jenkins Retry)",
                    skipWorkInProgressMergeRequest: true,
                    setBuildDescription: true,
                    addNoteOnMergeRequest: true,
                    addCiMessage: true,
                    addVoteOnMergeRequest: true,
                    acceptMergeRequestOnSuccess: false,
                    pendingBuildName: "Checkout",
                    branchFilterType: "NameBasedFilter",
                    cancelPendingBuildsOnUpdate: true,
                    includeBranchesSpec: "master",
                    secretToken: gitlabToken,
            )
        }
```

But it only triggers for pushes on main branch and MRs targeting the main branch.

(Building all commits its not a alternative because it may trigger many unnecessary pipelines)

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I follow:
IS: it only triggers for pushes on main branch and MRs targeting the main branch
SHOULD BE: build all Merge Requests and pushes on main branch 
but what is the difference ;) ?

Comment: The current config doesnt build MRs targeting other branches.

As is: Build only pushes on master (OK), Build only MRs targeting master (Not ok)

Comment: What i want: Build only pushes on master AND all MRs (regardless the target branch)